# neo4j is very slow with only one node

Tags: neo4j

I download `neo4j-community-2.1.4` binary versions, and simply extract and start `neo4j` by `bin/neo4j start`. I keep the default settings.

However, it's very slow when I insert only one node, and slowly when query it too. The way I insert and query is by visiting the web console(http://10.1.2.3:7474/browser). And it's also slow by using Neo4jPhp Client.

performance metrics:

1. neo4j browser( MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 100 ): Returned 1 row in 30022 ms
2. neo4jphp api(MATCH (n:' . $label . ') '. $where . ' RETURN n, ID(n), LABELS(n);): Total processing time: 21,036 ms; Peak memory: 5.1 MB.

I try again using curl, and the query is normal.

`curl -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0`

 It's also normal using http://10.1.2.3:7474/webadmin/#/console/shell

Comment: What is the your server configuration?

Comment: the default setting, except I uncomment this line: org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

Comment: What do you mean by 'slow'? Do you have some numbers?

Comment: Ignore the times from the neo4j-browser, it measures multiple roundtrips. The php driver should not be slow though, which one do you use?

Comment: my program use php driver, also use neo4j-browser to check the result

Comment: @MicTech neo4j browser(query one node -> MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 100 ): Returned 1 row in 30022 ms

Comment: @MichaelHunger how to ignore the times from neo4j-browser

Comment: Just don't look at them ;) use neo4j shell for measurement or http posts